Azure SFTP connection; can't get SSH host key fingerprint to work
For exercise purposes, I'm trying to connect an Azure blob storage via SFTP to Azure data factory's Copy Data tool. When I test the connection, the error reads:

Host key finger-print validation failed. Expected finger-print is 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 256 7Lrxb5z3CnAWI8pr2LK5eFHwDCl/Gtm/fhgGwB3zscw=', real finger-print is 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 256 cd:61:5e:c9:f2:0f:dd:84:f2:df:2a:dd:43:38:b2:94'.

I got the expected fingerprint from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-host-keys (West Europe, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256)
I put it in the GUI like this (added "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 256 " in front of the fingerprint):

Obviously, the fingerprint format is all wrong, so I think this might be a trivial question. However, I sincerely googled and came up empty.


According to the MS document the host key fingerprint provided by the SFTP server does not match the fingerprint expected by Azure Data Factory (ADF), that may be the reason to get above error. Provide real fingerprint provided in the error i.e. ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 256 cd:61:5e:c9:f2:0f:dd:84:f2:df:2a:dd:43:38:b2:94 for West Europe location in the linked service instead of previous one then your linked service will test successfully as shown below:


But I can't just copy the fingerprint from the error message, that would completely subvert the purpose of the host authentication.

You can check the simal post in Q&A.
